# What is the justification for the RHS of the identity $\binom{n + 2}{3} = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} i(n - i + 1)$?

Tags: combinatorics

If someone could provide some explanation/proof, it would be greatly appreciated.

$$\binom{n+2}{3} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i(n-i+1)$$

Q: What's the reasoning behind the RHS?

Comment: Your second question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2413861/how-to-prove-that-there-is-a-string-of-consecutive-days-in-which-a-factory-produ/2414082#2414082).

Comment: First part- Need to select $3$ distinct numbers out of $1,..,n+2$. Any $3$ numbers will have a middle element. So we can choose a middle element and then proceed to choose the smaller and bigger elements. Number of $3$-tuples with $i+1$ as the middle element will be $i(n-i+1)$. Sum this over $i$.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig fixed the question, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question count the three element subsets of $\{0,\dotsc,n+1\}$ in two different ways. There are $\binom{n+2}{3}$ such subsets. Classify the subsets based on their middle element (i.e. the element which is not maximum and not minimum). If the middle element is $i$, then there are $i$ choices for the minimum element and $(n+1)-(i+1)+1=n-i+1$ choices for the maximum element where $1\leq i\leq n$.

Comment: A minor suggestion:  There are $n + 1 - i$ elements larger than $i$.

Comment: makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Using the variation of Vandermonde's Identity proven in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/399213),
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^ni(n-i+1)
&=\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}\binom{i}{1}\binom{n+1-i}{1}\\
&=\binom{n+2}{3}
\end{align}
$$